# $q.reject does not rethrow the exception within $http.get().then().catch()

Tags: angularjs

I'm dealing with code like this:

```
return promise.then(function(url) {
    return $http.get(url, data);
}).then(function (response) {
    return response.data;
}).catch(function (response) {
    return $q.reject(response);
});
```

All I want to do is to reject the promise in the "catch" block so the exception is logged by my custom implementation of $exceptionHandler.

According to my [understanding of the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), the line below is supposed to rethrow the exception but it is not doing it. Thus, $exceptionHandler never handlers the exception:

```
return $q.reject(reason); // why isn't it rethrowing?
```

Chances are I'm misunderstanding the documentation.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$q.reject(response)`? `reason` isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for catching that @kiswa, I corrected the mistake. It doesn't work either way unfortunately. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Next thing to check... is there actually an exception being thrown? You could test it by explicitly throwing one in one of the `.then` functions.

Answer (score 2):

The error is re throwing - as controller can catch error and displays it.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('app', function($scope, service) {
    $scope.error = {}
    service
      .load('foo')
      .catch(function(error) {
        angular.extend($scope.error, {
          reason: error
        });
      });
  })
  .service('service', function($http, $q) {

    var promise = function promise() {
      var d = $q.defer();
      d.reject('some reason')
      return d.promise;
    }();

    this.load = function(url) {
      return promise
        .then(function() {
          return $http.get(url);
        })
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.data;
        })
        .catch(function(reason) {
          return $q.reject(reason);
        });
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller='app'>error: {{ error.reason }}</div>
</div>
```